# Attempted to call an undefined method named "getContext" of class "Swift_Mailer"

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-2.1, symfony-3.3

I'm trying to get the host of my site

The below code is used in symfony2.1 and now I have upgrade the symfony version to symfony3.3

```
public function __construct(EntityManager $entityManager) {
    $this->schemeAndHost = 'http://' . $this->router->getContext()->getHost();
}
```

Can anyone tell me how to get the host under Services MyManager.php file.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm a bit skeptical that the code you posted represents your actual code.  The error message implies that $this->router has been set to a Swift_Mailer object before the constructor is even being called?  Does not seem likely at all.

Comment: And on a somewhat unrelated topic, unless your app is trivial then upgrade to 2.8 first and get rid of all the depreciation notices.  Going directly from 2.1 to 3.3 is a huge leap.

Answer (score 0):

You should inject [`RequestStack`](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/request.html), and access to method `::getSchemeAndHttpHost` of current request.